# Counting assignments of elements of triples into bins

Tags: combinatorics

We have a family of $N$ triples $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$, ($1\le i \le N$) and $N$ bins. We want to distribute the elements of each triple into bins such that each bin has three elements and no bin gets the three elements of any triple ($(x_i,y_i,z_i)$).

Note that triples do not share any elements. The total number of all elements is $3N$.

> In how many ways can we perform this?

Comment: What have you tried?  Also, for clarity:  How can a bin be empty?  you have $3N$ objects in total and each used bin "has three elements"  so that's all the bins, yes?

Comment: @lulu please see the edited post.

Comment: Still unclear.  Might help to work explicit examples.  I guess (though I am not at all sure) that you meant to require that $N$ was a multiple of $3$?  If so, then what are the answers for $N=3,6$?

Comment: @lulu The problem is completely different after the revision.

Comment: So, first permute the $x's$, now permute that list so that there are no fixed points, now permute that list so that there are no matches with either of the first two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

There are $\frac{(3N)!}{3!^N}$ ways to distribute the elements over the bins. If $k$ particular bins contain all the elements of a triple, there are $\frac{(3(N-k))!}{3!^{N-k}}$ ways to distribute the remaining elements over the remaining triples. There are $\binom Nk$ ways to choose the $k$ particular bins and $\frac{N!}{(N-k)!}$ ways to choose triples for them. Thus the number of distributions in which no bin contains all elements of a triple is

$$
\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^k\binom Nk\frac{N!}{(N-k)!}\frac{(3(N-k))!}{3!^{N-k}}\;.
$$